# How to use left join if left table has multiple field associated with other table?

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have two table: **user** and **city**
Fields of user table :

```
user_id, user_birth_city, user_current_city, user_school_city
```

Fields of user table :

```
city_id, city_name
```

How to show the user's all three city name?

Comment: You need to do 3 joins, and rename the table city in each join, using something like "SELECT user.*, alias1.column as columnAlias1, alias2.column as columnAlias2 .. From user... Left JOIN tableName alias1 ON.. LEFT JOIN tableName alias2 On... "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` on table `city` for 3 times can do it

```
SELECT u.user_id,c1.city_name,c2.city_name,c3.city_name 
  FROM user u
  LEFT JOIN city c1 ON u.user_birth_city=c1.city_id
  LEFT JOIN city c2 ON u.user_current_city=c2.city_id
  LEFT JOIN city c3 ON u.user_school_city=c3.city_id
```

NOTES:`user` is a reserved table in `MySQL`,you table name should not be it

Answer (score 0):

```
Select b.city_id, b.city_name from user_table a, city_table b where 
(a.user_birth_city=b.city_name OR a.user_current_city=b.city_name OR 
a.user_school_city=b.city_name) AND user_id='(whatever your user_id is)';
```

SQL folks will comment that this query will not work because of the comma in the from, but I assure you, it will.